# Swift Cannot convert value of type CBPeripheral to expected argument type

Tags: objective-c, swift, cbperipheral

The code I have:

```
func didDiscoverBLE(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral!, address: String!, rssi: Int32) {


DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in

                    // Handle Discovery
                    self.arrayPeripehral.contains(where:peripheral)
                        return
                    })
            self.arrayPeripehral.append(peripheral)
            let title: String = "\(peripheral.name) \(address) (RSSI:\(rssi))"
            self.arrayPeripheralName.append(title)
```

---

In this line i have a problem:

```
self.arrayPeripehral.contains(where:peripheral)
    return
})
```

Has anyone an idea?

---

Here is the code I copied from the obective c to the swift and got stuck on this error

```
 - (void)didDiscoverBLE:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral address:(NSString *)address rssi:(int)rssi
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // Handle Discovery
            if([arrayPeripehral containsObject:peripheral])
                return;

            [arrayPeripehral addObject:peripheral];

            NSString * title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ (RSSI:%d)", peripheral.name, address, rssi];

            [arrayPeripheralName addObject:title];
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `arrayPeripehral`.

Comment: var arrayPeripehral = [Any]()var arrayPeripheralName = [Any]()

Comment: i am use framework obj c and i have briddging file and i declare  peripheral

var peripheral: CBPeripheral?
var arrayPeripehral = [Any]()
var arrayPeripheralName = [Any]()

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding infomation in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of `arrayPeripehral` to `[CBPeripheral]` from `[Any]` that will give compiler more idea about its type then use `contains(where:)` like this to check array contains object or not.

```
var arrayPeripehral = [CBPeripheral]()
```

Now use `contains(where:)` this way to check array contains object or not.

```
if self.arrayPeripehral.contains(where: { $0.name == peripheral.name }) {
    return
}
```

Also change type declaration of `arrayPeripheralName` to `[String]` from `[Any]` as of you are appending only `String` object in it.

```
var arrayPeripheralName = [String]()
```

Comment: here is my code 
but device is not finded
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0YSY8kyU68lVHo1aVU2a29aY0E

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0YSY8kyU68lbU9Yc2hfUlNFbkk
thats project i am convert to swift 3

Comment: @AlexArshansky You have asked to correct the code and that I have suggested If you have any more question ask new question here

Comment: THANKS ALOT !!! 
i dumb i forgot 
myApp.myBle.myDiscoverDelegate = self;

Comment: i see device but i don stil make a connect

Comment: @AlexArshansky Welcome mate :)

Comment: if you are here help another one task

Comment: @AlexArshansky Ask the new question here and send me link of it in comment will look on to it, if I have solution for it will post one

Comment: another trouble ^^